# How to grab the audio channel from an MP4 video file into a separate audio file?

Tags: audio, video, video-editing, video-encoding

Having an MPEG4 (MP4 container, H264 AVC video, AAC audio) video clip downloaded from YouTube, how to separate its audio channel into an independent audio (without de&re-compressing the audio preferably) file with free Linux tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know there is only 1 audio stream and that it is `aac`, then you only need this:

```
ffmpeg -acodec copy -i "movie.mp4" -y "audio.aac"
```

If you want to script the  first audio stream ID and codec-type/file-extension, you can use this:

```
eval $(ffmpeg -i "movie.mp4" 2>&1 |awk '/Stream.*Audio/{print "stream=" $2 ";codec=" $4}' |head -n1)
stream=${stream:1}; stream=${stream/:/}
extn=${codec/,/}; [[ $extn == "aac" ]] || 
    { echo "You need to manually set the fiie extension. Codec type is: $codec"; exit 1; } 

ffmpeg -map $stream -acodec copy -i "movie.mp4" "audio.$extn"
```

Comment: eval: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Perhaps `ffmpeg -i` in not outputing a single line which matches  *`/Stream.*Audio/`* line... If there is more than one, then to grab the first one, you need `eval $(ffmpeg -i "movie.mp4" 2>&1 |awk '/Stream.*Audio/{print "stream=" $2 ";codec=" $4} |head -n1)` .... Otherwise just experiment with `ffmpeg -i` and see what it needs, or for a one-off,  manually enter the correct filetype...

Comment: By the way, do you happen to know a similar trick for FLV files? ffmpeg says "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'audioFile'". Seems it thinks it's webm.

Answer (score 2):

Considering Youtube videos, extracting audio from video may not be necessary, as the **audio tracks can be downloaded separately** as
such by using Firefox with the latest Flashgot addon or by using **mps-youtube** (it is a tool meant to play and download audio tracks from youtube: more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229791/32012)).

---

Considering mp4 video files:

As answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229626/32012), one can us a more generic command without the need for the specific names of the files, and add that to the File Manager custom menu, like:

```
ffmpeg -i "$0" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${0%%.*}".m4a
```

(Using `.m4a` is preferable as it is more largely supported as a container for `.aac`, but you can use the raw `.aac` instead if you wish.)

Also, this command run in a terminal will extract audio tracks from all mp4 files in the current folder:

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "${i}" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${i%.mp4}.m4a"; done
```

([here](https://askubuntu.com/a/235912/47206) the source post)

---

See comments and related info in the linked answers and questions on how to use such commands in the context-menus of file managers.

---

Above and other similar commands can be used also for extracting audio from other types of video files, by replacing accordingly the input and output extensions.

The first command works as such for `flv` too; but for other video, just replace `m4a` with whatever audio is contained by the video clip. The second command needs replacing both video and audio extensions if applied to different  types of video files.

Usually, `mp4` and `flv` files contain `aac` audio, `Webm` files contain `ogg` and `avi` files contain `mp3` audio. To be sure what audio is contained by the video, use  `mediainfo`: **[mediainfo-GUI](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download)**, or just install `mediainfo` and in Terminal: `mediainfo <file>`.