# Custom action calling avconv in Thunar and Dolphin

Tags: thunar, avconv, dolphin

I like to use a command like

`avconv -i %f -map 0:1 -c:a copy %f.m4a`

in the custom actions of Thunar or Dolphin to extract audio from mp4 and flv without transcoding.

But that will output a name that contains the extension of the input file:

From a video "name.mp4" I get an audio file called "name.mp4.m4a".

How to adjust the command so that the output is "name.m4a"?

Comment: Maybe something like: `avconv -i %f -map 0:1 -c:a copy ${%f%%.*}.m4a`, if the custom actions are run through bash.

Comment: @muru - It's the custom actions in Dolphin/KDE what I use for the moment, and there, in the .desktop file that is used, if I replace my command with yours it does nothing. About bash I have to get more info...

Comment: Run your commands through `bash`: `bash -c 'avconv -i "$0" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${0%%.*}".m4a' %f`

Comment: It works. Would you mind posting as answer too? Thank you for the swift reply!

Comment: If you have an improved command, I'll delete my answer, no problem.

Comment: @muru - what I meant was: please post an answer, or, if YOU prefer not to, I'll post YOUR info for you. :) It's done now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the string manipulation features of bash, by running your command through bash:

```
bash -c 'avconv -i "$0" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${0%%.*}".m4a' %f
```

(I'm assuming that your file manager will pass a filename like `foo bar.mp4` as a single argument.)

Note that `bash` has both `${var%%suffix}` and `${var%suffix}` - the former is greedy (`foo.bar.mp4` will become `foo` with the first and `foo.bar` with the second). In this case, I'm aiming to use the latter, and assuming that `%%` will be replaced by `%` by the file manager since `%` is apparently a special character here.