# Audio-only youtube player

Tags: audio, youtube

I would like to find an application external to the internet browser that would play only youtube sound.

Preferably a very light one, CLI or GUI.

Comment: What research have you done?  What possibilities have you already considered?  [Doing research before you ask helps you ask a better question, and sharing your research helps everyone.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @D.W. - I knew about youtube being played in external video players like VLC, SMPlayer, MPV, but not about any application that would do what I am asking above, and I didn't thought there is one, when I found about MPS-Youtube. Then, I thought it would be nice to [create a question in order to provide this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/210628) - also [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). - Other answers and comments came with new suggestions.

Comment: @cipricus: see also [my answer to this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56773/listen-to-music-on-youtube-without-video/95360#95360)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is youtube-dl that lets you download youtube videos from the cli. There is also a new(ish) tool called mps-youtube, that I haven't personally used, but looks like it does exactly what you want.

https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube

Give it a try and let us know if it works

---

MPS is available in Ubuntu repos.

Launch the MPS console with

```
mpsyt
```

To search youtube in mps console:

```
/<your_search_term>
```

After searching a term, and then selecting a number, the stream will play sound; there are play/pause, seek, volume options:

[image]

To see options:

```
mpsyt h
```

[image]

More detailed options:

```
mpsyt help search
```

[image]

```
mpsyt help download
```

[image]

After searching and then selecting the number of the stream with a command that would show download options:

```
d <number>
```

[image]

Playlists can also be searched in the PLS console with

```
pls <search_term>
```

or even simpler

```
//<serch_term>
```

Comment: I knew about mps and that gave me the idea to ask a question to find if there are others. if you don't mind I'll edit your answer on MPS to add more info because I've just used it and it's great

Comment: Sure, please do so. As someone else has mentioned, there is also vlc, and I believe mplayer with some tricks can also be used.

Comment: vlc and other external players with an option for 'no video' are interesting too. But I think MPS is no 1 for now, being so specialized in what the question asks.

Comment: I thought mpsyt would be sweet, but it seems there's some bugs to fix when it comes to its handling of things that run over 30mins, like symphonies or mixes. Cuts out partway through. Maybe something that could be mitigated through downloading the file and then listening to it through the interface it provides

Comment: It looks like a question and answer designed to promote a product, just check dates and comments, plus the asker's account has been deactivated... The answer by @marco should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 32):

VLC can do that.

- Use `cvlc` to turn off the GUI
- Reject the video to just play the audio using `--vout none` or `--no-video`

Example:

```
cvlc --vout none <URL>
cvlc --no-video <URL>
```

Comment: That can be used in Firefox with Openwith addon: add usr/bin/cvlc,  edit argument to `cvlc --vout none` or `cvlc --no-video`, and edit name to something like 'VLC Audio'. Then, in the Firefox, right click on a youtube link, 'Open with': VLC Audio. To shut down `pkill vlc`. -- But even so the interaction with the playing track is very limited and the results are not as good as with the more specialized MPS.

Comment: for mplayer, it would be `mplayer -novideo`

Answer (score 18):

You can do this with [yturl](https://github.com/cdown/yturl), for example, using [mpv](https://mpv.io) or [mplayer](https://www.mplayerhq.hu):

```
mpv --no-video "$(yturl <url>)"
mplayer -novideo "$(yturl <url>)"
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of yturl.

Comment: Would it be better then `mpv --no-video <url>`? I tested the latter and it starts after a minute or more

Comment: @cipricus "Better" is subjective. I don't know why it would take a minute or more, but if it's network related, you can try using a lower bitrate, for example using `mpv --no-video "$(yturl -q low <url>)"`.

Comment: without `yturl`, `mpv` already has ` --ytdl-format=mp4` (or something else like `--ytdl-format=best`), there are also options for quality. I don't know if it's as powerful as `yturl`, but I wanted to say that `mpv` has native features quite similar to this. (I don't know if what I said were true 5 years ago)

Answer (score 9):

In order to **select only the audio stream and send it to a player** (video players like SMPlayer, VLC, mpv, mplayer, Dragon Player, Totem, but also audio players like Audacious):

- **SMTube**

It is able search, list and play Youtube videos, and is meant to work with SMPlayer, but can be used separately. It has a setting to add/use different players and also **an option to select only audio**.

Go to settings

[image]

Then select and/or add players to be used, and edit their setting to play also audio (for video players) or only audio, for audio players like Audacious.

[image]

[image]

They can then be found when right-clicking a title and selecting 'Open audio'.

[image]

---

- [**Kaku player**](http://kaku.rocks/).

Can be found as deb and other formats [here](https://github.com/EragonJ/Kaku/releases). It supports more than Youtube (Baidu, Video etc) and has a setting to play only audio:

[image]

It can *create and save playlists*.

---

- **With the Flashgot addon in Firefox** by adding the external player as Flashgot "downloader" (like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/169410/47206)) and then, after starting the youtube video in Firefox, using Flashgot to play only the audio stream by going to 'Available formats/DASH (separate audio and video tracks)' and selecting the specific audio track.

[image: flashgot-select-audio-track]

It will start after a few seconds, some players after more than others. The fastest seems to be **SMPlayer**.

To use the 'no-video' arguments with the Firefox addons, the way to do it is like so for Flashgot:

[image]

and like so for OpenWith:

[image]

More on playing embedded videos in external players, in [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/q/819187/162573).

Also, an idea is that using certain internet browsers (Seamonkey, Epiphany etc - but not Firefox and Chrome), an Youtube title could be dragged and dropped onto `mpv` or a `mpv` fron-tend to play Youtube videos.

For the present purpose those players should be started with a 'no video' argument.

---

**Youtube-Viewer**

(more [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/youtube-viewer-complete-youtube-client.html)) can be adjusted to play only sound.

For *ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-viewer
```

In spite of what is said at the link above, it works fine with mplayer.

Just like MPS from the other answer, it is meant to search, play and download youtube streams, only that by default it will play the video and not just the audio stream. It can use mplayer as external player.

The command for mplayer without video is

`mplayer -novideo`

To start Youtube Viewer with this option:

```
youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer -novideo
```

That can be added in a .desktop file with the lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Youtube Audio-only
Exec=bash -c 'youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer -novideo'
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=youtube-viewer
```

When started, just type the search and then the number of the track to play.

[image]

Closing the terminal will close the play.

(`d <number>` will download that video, by default as webm. And, of course, Youtube-Viewer is meant for **seeing** the youtube **video** too. For that, just use `youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer` or `youtube-viewer --video-player=mpv`.)

Comment: + for youtube-viewer, although it needs an api key since (...??) - but see: https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer/issues/308 and there is also a gui-version of it: https://awesomeopensource.com/project/trizen/youtube-viewer?categoryPage=3

Answer (score 4):

You can simply pipe the output of youtube-dl with your preferred format into ffplay.

example:

```
youtube-dl -f 251 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdRJMuOFO88 -o - | ffplay -nodisp -autoexit -i -
```

to list available formats use:

```
youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdRJMuOFO88
```

Answer (score 2):

[Headset](http://headsetapp.co/) app lets you play only the audio from YouTube. It has built in search functionality where you can search directly into YouTube. It also provides you an option to play songs from particular subreddit. But it opens a small window, which plays the lowest possible quality of video from YouTube.

The application is  opensource and available as a .deb file for Ubuntu and also for other platforms like Windows and Mac OS.

[image]

Comment: As mentioned, this is not "audio only", as it keeps a small video window. But that separate window can be minimized, while the main window only shows an image. The memory use is low, even if it starts 4-5 different processes.

Answer (score 1):

For streaming YouTube audio from the command-line, without messing with API keys,
you can also create `.m3u` playlists for playing video in MPV, etc.

AUR Package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/yt-bin

[image: yt-bin]

Answer (score 1):

[QMPlayer2](https://github.com/zaps166/QMPlay2#youtube)

[image]

Right-click > Audio only > Play

I prefer it as [Appimage](https://github.com/zaps166/QMPlay2/releases/tag/21.03.09).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AyushRawal/YTMusic).

I wrote this script for listening to music on youtube but can be used to listen any audio.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [AudioTube](https://apps.kde.org/en-gb/audiotube/). This is an application developed by KDE Community for listening to music from YouTube.

If you use KDE, this is probably the best option. On the other hand, on other desktops (e.g. Gnome), it may not display well (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=466901). You can work around that using adwaita-qt and a legacy icon theme.

[image: AudioTube Screenshot]